# Python decimal issue

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to analyze data with Python. I created a csv file in excel before. But when I show the table with python, only one column seems to have all numbers in decimals. Excel also looks fine, but when I show it in python it looks decimal. Please help!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("covıd.csv" , sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
df
```

[image]

The Total Case part looks decimal. not improving. It wasn't like this before.

Comment: try checking the datatype of "Dailycase" and convert "Totalcase" to that type

Comment: When you read a file into pandas, you can choose the datatype of a column with: `pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', dtype={'column_name': data_type})`.

Comment: You can check if the decimal point used in the original file is dot (.) or comma (,), and set the parameter in `pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', decimal=',')`

Comment: Unfortunately I tried all of them but it did not. I wonder if there is an error in excel.

Comment: As @Dinesh suggested can you please comment the type of the columns `Dailycase` and `Totalcase`? I think the column `Totalcase` has no NaN values as a result it is decimal. However, the columns has them. Hence, it may be getting converted type `object`.

Comment: You gave me an idea, thank you all :) I corrected some parts of the Excel spreadsheet and gave the NaN value. It was in the first parts . Thanks :)